# Too large variances from the covariance matrix when fitting data using curve_fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, least-squares, variance

I have some troubles when try to fit my data using curve_fit.

First, I have too large variances which I get from the covariance matrix: relative magnitudes of standard errors are more than 100% for some of the found parameters. However, the fit curve fits very well on the data but if I give the parameters the deviations indicated in the covariance matrix, the curve will deviate very strongly. The variances become smaller if I lower the degree of the polynomial with which I fit the data. But then the curve lays worse on the data. Another thing that puzzles me is that the initial guess for parametres does not improve the situation.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 

#experimental_data
x=np.array([1842., 1885., 2149., 2164., 2195., 2208., 2234., 2254., 2266., 2284., 2292., 2315., 2334., 2350., 2361., 2381., 2387., 2427., 2435., 2458., 2484., 2498., 2563., 2592.,  830.,  269., 1498.,1918., 2100., 2112., 2312.])
y=np.array([5336., 5401., 5852., 5882., 5945., 5976., 6030., 6074., 6096., 6143., 6164., 6217., 6267., 6305., 6334., 6383., 6402., 6507., 6533., 6599., 6678., 6717., 6929., 7032., 4358., 4047., 4916., 5461., 5770., 5791., 6234.])

#fitting_function
def f_fit(x,a,b,c,d,g):
    return a*x**4+b*x**3+c*x**2+d*x+g

X=np.linspace(min(x),max(x))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f = f_fit, xdata= x, ydata=y)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.plot(x,y, 'x') #experimental_data
plt.plot(X,f_fit(X, *popt))

perr=np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)) #standard errors
#perturbed plots
plt.plot(X,f_fit(X, *popt+perr))
plt.plot(X,f_fit(X, *popt-perr))
```

[image: That's what i get]

Second, If I add `absoulute_sigma=True`, I get much smaller deviations for plot. But it doesn't make any sense for me. In the least squares method we generally don't know about the uncertainty in ydata, but most of the times it works correctly. And I don't understand why adding `absoulute_sigma=True` makes the variances so much smaller.

`popt, pcov = curve_fit(f = f_fit, xdata= x, ydata=y)` leads me to such plots:

[image: Absolute_sigma=True]

Sorry, If my question is primitive, I am just the beginner in this.

Comment: Are you asking a programming question or a math question?

Comment: I don't really know. That depends on where I am wrong: in code or in math.

Comment: As a test, try "numpy,polyfit(x, y, 4)" with the returned parameters as your initial parameters for curve_fit(). Note from the numpy documentation that polyfit() returns "Polynomial coefficients, highest power first."

Comment: @JamesPhillips I already found the initial parameters, albeit in a slightly different way. In any case, fitting is not a problem; the found curve fits the data well. But the variances (and hence standard errors) of the found parameters still remain large. That is the main problem.

Comment: My meaning was to try this as a test.

Comment: I found that a three-parameter Michaelis-Menten With Offset equation "y = (a * x) / (b + x) + Offset" gives a better fit than a five-parameter 4th-order polynomial, with fitted parameters a = -1.5845078644535824E+03, b = -3.9186790741574605E+03, and Offset = 3.9325458300884811E+03 yielding RMSE = 5.438. The 4th-order polynomial gives me an RMSE of 6.042.

Comment: I apologize if I speak out unclearly or incorrectly. As I understand it, RMSE evaluates the accuracy of the fitting. But I am quite satisfied with the accuracy that the curve_fit and my program provide me. I am only concerned about the standard errors of the parameters that I find from the covariance matrix I get from curve_fit. I suppose that they cannot be so large, given the accuracy of the fit. So, I believe somewhere I'm wrong or I don't know about some specificities.

Answer (score 1):

curve_fit() estimates parameter values and their covariances, and

```
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
```

provides standard errors of parameter estimates for a, b, c, d, g.

The width of the error bands in your plot is determined by

```
f_fit(x,*popt+perr) - f_fit(x,*popt),
```

which is equal to

```
perr(a)*x^4 + perr(b)*x^3 + perr(c)*x^2+ perr(d)*x + perr(g)
```

First, you can see that the larger x, the wider the error band, even when parameters are precisely estimated and perr values are very small. Therefore, the error bands may become very wide at large x values because the higher order terms of the polynomial are very large. The table below shows the contribution of each polynomial term to the width of your standard error bands for each value in X, and you can clearly see that higher order terms make error bands very wide at larger X values:

```
       perr(g)  perr(d)X  perr(c)X^2  perr(b)X^3 perr(a)X^4  f_fit(X, *perr)
X                       
269.00    22.84    27.38      9.390     1.23        0.06      60.90
316.41    22.84    32.20      13.00     2.01        0.11      70.15
363.82    22.84    37.03      17.18     3.05        0.18      80.29
...
...
2497.18   22.84   254.17     809.55   986.50      409.22    2482.27
2544.59   22.84   258.99     840.58  1043.76      441.19    2607.36
2592.00   22.84   263.82     872.19  1103.19      475.00    2737.04
```

Since your parameters are very precisely estimated, and some of them are virtually zero - in your example,

```
popt = [ 1.23384779e-10, -4.87863958e-07,  9.15360533e-04, -8.15143637e-02, 4.01221128e+03]
```

and

```
perr = [1.05233894e-11 6.33499440e-08 1.29819675e-04 1.01781887e-01 2.28383194e+01]
```

you might benefit from dropping x^4 and x^3 terms from f_fit(), and it will help reduce the error of the regression without substantially affecting the fit of the curve.

Regarding absolute_sigma=True, you should only use this option when you specify sigma parameter, i.e. when you have a good reason to apply weights to your observations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Don't standard errors of the parameters indicate the degree of uncertainty of the parameters determined by the uncertainty in the values of y? Then how does such a good fit come about, if they become so large? Also, if we drop $x^4$ (or especially $x^3$) term, then even by eye it will be noticeable that the fitting has worsened. Your answer also shows that the largest relative error is provided by the x-parameter. I tried to remove it from the fitting function and the errors really decreased noticeably with a slight deterioration of the fitting. That's confusing.

Comment: The regression curve fits your data very well and regression errors indeed must be small. However, the error bands you create do not represent regression errors. Regression errors are err=(y-f_fit(x,*popt)). If you want to plot regression line +/- standard error of regression, you calculate standard deviation of  err and plot f_fit(x,*popt) +/- std_err

Answer (score 0):

To start, I'll say that I agree with others that sigma_absolute is not appropriate here. It's for when you have a known error on your points that you put in as the parameter sigma. Otherwise it should do nothing, and if it does something, it's bad (it might assert that all errors are numerically equal to 1).

And next, the central issue here is that your parameters have so much covariance. This is a math problem not a programming problem - but it's not a "primitive question" at all. While it's true that the error on each individual parameter is the square root of the corresponding diagonal element of the covariance matrix, that doesn't necessarily mean that the fit considers it likely that all of your fit parameters can have errors in the same direction. For example, it could be that the fit is saying "the x^4 term can be larger than the fit value, but only if the x^3 term is smaller than the fit value."

To make this problem more clear, consider the following pathologically combination of dataset+fit function

```
xstest=[]
ystest=[]
startx=1000
endx=1100
for i in range(startx,endx):
    xstest.append(i)
    ystest.append(np.random.uniform(-1,1))
plt.scatter(xstest,ystest)

def myline(x,*p):
    m,b=p
    return m*x+b
popt,pcov=curve_fit(myline,xstest,ystest,p0=[0,0])

plt.plot([startx,endx],[startx*popt[0]+popt[1],endx*popt[0]+popt[1]])
plt.plot([startx,endx],[startx*(popt[0]+np.sqrt(pcov[0,0]))+(popt[1]+np.sqrt(pcov[1,1])),endx*(popt[0]+np.sqrt(pcov[0,0]))+(popt[1]+np.sqrt(pcov[1,1]))])
plt.plot([startx,endx],[startx*(popt[0]-np.sqrt(pcov[0,0]))+(popt[1]-np.sqrt(pcov[1,1])),endx*(popt[0]-np.sqrt(pcov[0,0]))+(popt[1]-np.sqrt(pcov[1,1]))])
print(pcov)
plt.show()
```

We get this plot, which clearly shows our "one sigma" error bars way outside of what can reasonably be inferred from our data

[bad errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56FUb.png)

And indeed our covariance matrix has a large negative value in the off-diagonal

```
[[ 3.67613410e-06 -3.85810273e-03]
[-3.85810273e-03  4.05214195e+00]]
```

So how do we properly plot what you meant to plot: the highest values of the fit function that are one sigma away from the central fit function? Start by finding the gradient of the fit function with respect to the parameters. In my case it's [x,1]. In yours it's [x^4,x^3,x^2,x,1]. But either way I'll call it "grad". And I'll call my_error_vec the vector of parameter errors.

The condition on the parameter errors is that my_error_vec^T X pcov^(-1) X my_error_vec=1. (You have to trust me on this). Note that in my example if I assume my_error_vec=[sqrt(popt[0,0]),0] I get 1300, not 1. So in my case it is NOT reasonable to assume that the error is sqrt(popt[0,0]) in just one direction. That is moving way too far in one direction without also having a reasonable negative value on the other parameter.

So then the question of finding the maximum possible value of f(x) given pcov is a maximum given constraint problem which can be nicely solved using Lagrange multipliers (lambda is my arbitrary multiplier).

Condition 1: lambda * grad=pcov^(-1) * params

Condition 2: params^T*(pcov^(-1))*params=1

Solving cond 1 and inserting it into cond 2 gives:

lambda=+-1/sqrt(grad^T * pcov * grad)

and finally we get the parameters (critically a function of x through grad!)
params=+-lambda * pcov * grad

^one of these solutions will give the maximum possible value of f, and one the minimum possible value of f

So here's my adjusted code

```
plt.show()
xstest=[]
ystest=[]
startx=1000
endx=1100
for i in range(startx,endx):
    xstest.append(i)
    ystest.append(np.random.uniform(-1,1))
plt.scatter(xstest,ystest)
#plt.ylim(-2,2)

def myline(x,*p):
    m,b=p
    return m*x+b
popt,pcov=curve_fit(myline,xstest,ystest,p0=[0,0])
invpcov=np.linalg.inv(pcov)

myerr=np.array([np.sqrt(pcov[0,0]),0])

def my_err_vec(x):
    gradvec=np.array([x,1])
    norm=np.matmul(gradvec.T,np.matmul(pcov,gradvec))
    lambd=np.sqrt(1/norm)
    return np.matmul(pcov,lambd*gradvec)


plt.plot([startx,endx],[startx*popt[0]+popt[1],endx*popt[0]+popt[1]])
ys_err_pos=[myline(x,*(popt-my_err_vec(x))) for x in xstest]
plt.plot(xstest,ys_err_pos)
ys_err_pos=[myline(x,*(my_err_vec(x)+popt)) for x in xstest]
plt.plot(xstest,ys_err_pos)
plt.show()
```

And I get the nice result here - which has all the qualitative features you might expect, like the error lines being nonlinear and bigger on the edge than in the center.
[Fixed errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEwLz.png)